# How to check and insert values to list C#

Tags: c#, list

After accessing the local file, I need to check and add the missing column (walmart) before converting it to xml. I confirm data is available in the csv file.

Currently I am getting an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Code:

```
string[] vs = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/Users/Raw.csv");

var lines = new List <String>();
            
lines = vs.ToList();

foreach (var check in lines)
{
    if (!check.Contains("Walmart"))
    {
        lines.Insert(0,"Walmart");
    }
}

foreach (var shw in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(shw);
}
```

Comment: You are changing the List within the foreach loop. You can only change it outside.

Comment: Think carefully about what that first loop is meant to do: you check if each item is `Walmart"; each time there is not a match, it adds "Walmart".  Probably not what you really want.  Create a function which checks the *entire list* then add depending on the result of that method.88

Comment: Do I get this right: What you **want** to do is if in the (CSV) line, there is no "Walmart" you want to add it _as a column to that line_. Is that correct? But what you **are** doing is: you try to insert a line consisting of the word "Walmart" into the list of lines.

Comment: BTW: I'd suggest (and strongly encourage) to use a CSV-Library that takes away a lot of headaches. And you will have those if in fact columns are missing. If it's only an empty column sometimes, you could fix that much more easily after converting the CSV to a collection of RowModels, that could for example have a Property pre-filled with a default value.

Comment: @Fildor, after making sure the "walmart" column exist, my next step is to convert the csv file to xml file.

Comment: Yes. Whatever you do with it, you shouldn't fix broken input. It should be fixed by the one creating the input, so you are provided with valid input.

Answer (score 2):

Techically, if you want just amend your current code you can *count* how many `Walmarts` we should add:

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:/Users/Raw.csv")
  .ToList();

int walmartsToAdd = 0;

foreach (var check in lines) 
  if (!check.Contains("Walmart"))
    walmartsToAdd += 1;

if (walmartsToAdd > 0)
  lines.InsertRange(0, Enumerable.Repeat("Walmart", walmartsToAdd));

foreach (var shw in lines)
  Console.WriteLine(shw);
```

But it seems, that you should modify *lines*: `abc,def` => `Walmart,abc,def`. If it's your case you can just add `Select`

```
var lines = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:/Users/Raw.csv")
  .Select(line => line.StartsWith("Walmart,")  ? line : $"Walmart,{line}")
  .ToList();

foreach (var shw in lines)
  Console.WriteLine(shw);
```

Comment: If we assume that "Walmart" is always the text for the first column in the CSV then I would use _line.StartsWith("Walmart,")_ otherwise there is a more complex problem

Comment: @Steve: Nice catch, my bad! You are absolutely right!

Comment: Good answer as usual Dmitry!

Comment: And if only in some lines a whole column is missing (not empty - _missing_) I'd be pressing to fix the creator of that CSV (which is broken) rather than try to fix the corrupt data ex post. Just as a non-technical approach to the actual problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the source Enumerable while iterating on it. I always imagine that the enumerator has inside a current index and if for example, the change would delete all the members the index wouldn't make any sense anymore. The easy solution is to iterate on something else / make a copy.

Here instead of lines you can try iterating on the variable 'vs'.

```
var vs = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:/Users/Raw.csv");

var lines = vs.ToList();

foreach (var check in vs)
{
    if (!check.Contains("Walmart"))
    {
        lines.Insert(0, "Walmart");
    }
}

foreach (var shw in lines)
{
    Console.WriteLine(shw);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this helps the OP. Now, you have a List of string with only the lines that originally where without the "Walmart" word, and an array with the whole set of lines unchanged